# MVC3 RadioButton

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, radio-button

I'm working with C# + MVC3.
I have a radiobutton on a form, but I'm having some problems.

At Index.cshtml, I have:

```
<div class="display-label">
    Label
</div>
<div class="display-field">@Html.RadioButton("rdActive", ((FakeClass)ViewBag.FakeFilter).Situation, "S");
```

At Index of my Controller, i have:

```
    ViewBag.FakeFilter = new FakeClass()
    {
        Situacao = (Request.Form["rdActive"] == "" ? null : Request.Form["rdActive"])
    }
```

And I'm getting ArgumentNullPointerException

Comment: can please copy/paste the error from stack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what I understand of your error it's throws Nullpontier because you're receiving empty in the `Request.Form["rdActive"]` so when the code passes for the action returns null to the viewbag.

Now what i see strange it's that the overload of the helper receives in the last parameters a Boolean and you're passing an string with "s".

this

```
@Html.RadioButton("rdActive", ((FakeClass)ViewBag.FakeFilter).Situation, "S")
```

Should be

```
@Html.RadioButton("rdActive", ((FakeClass)ViewBag.FakeFilter).Situation, true)
```

or

```
@Html.RadioButton("rdActive", ((FakeClass)ViewBag.FakeFilter).Situation, false)
```

Check the parameters

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks Jorge! Worked for me:
 @Html.RadioButton("rdFake", "S",true)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that ViewBag is not available in your view, try using TempData["FakeFilter"] which is accesible from any view and is deleted after you read it (by default)